# how to await in for loop firebase cloud function using typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have a query to find users from firestore DB. Then I need to find which user is online or not. I used build presence(real-time database) for that.

In my logic, sometimes return an empty array. `status` is `true` on realTime DB. I think it will return without finish for a loop.

```
const users: Array<any> = [];

await asyncForEach(query.docs, async (loc: any) => {
  const data = loc.data();
  await rtDb.ref(data.uid).once('value', function (snap) {
    if (snap.val().status === true) {
      users.push(data);
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(`${e}`)
  });
});

return users;


async function asyncForEach(array: Array<any>, callback: Function) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to say where the error may be. If you are getting an empty array, are you sure `loc.data()` is not throwing an error? Or there are other errors stopping the push from happening?

You could use a combination of promises and `Promise.all`. You can use a standard`for-of`

#### Promises

You can turn the realTime DB data return into a promise. [Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
  const rtDbPromise = (loc: QueryDoc): Promise<UserData | null> => {
    const data = loc.data();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      rtDb.ref(data.uid).once("value", (snap: Snap) => {
        try {
          if (snap.val().status) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

#### Promise all

Then you can add all your promises to an array and use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Looping with a [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
type UserData = { uid: string };
type Snap = { val: () => { status: boolean } };
type QueryDoc = { data: () => UserData };
type MockRtDb = {
  ref: (
    uid: string
  ) => {
    once: (type: "value", callback: (snap: Snap) => void) => Promise<void>;
  };
};

async function getOnlineUsers(): Promise<UserData[]> {
  const rtDb = {} as MockRtDb;

  // Create the async call here (Promise)
  const rtDbPromise = (loc: QueryDoc): Promise<UserData | null> => {
    const data = loc.data();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      rtDb.ref(data.uid).once("value", (snap: Snap) => {
        try {
          if (snap.val().status) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          // This will throw an error. If any promises fail, Promise.all will throw as well.
          // Maybe return null if you don't want errors. Read the docs for more info
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const dataArray: QueryDoc[] = [];
  const promise: Promise<UserData | null>[] = [];

  for (const data of dataArray) {
    promise.push(rtDbPromise(data));
  }

  const dataWithNulls: (UserData | null)[] = await Promise.all(promise);
  // Filter out the nulls
  return dataWithNulls.filter((item) => item !== null);
}

const onlineUsers = await getOnlineUsers();
```

Comment: @BloodLoss Sure np. Hope it goes well